# How to configure Kannel with Linux web server?

Tags: kannel

I downloaded the Kannel software from the net and uploaded the software into the web server.

Now I need to compile and run Kannel. How can I run `configure` and `install.sh` files?

Can you provide the solution?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would install it:

latest svn:

svn co https://svn.kannel.org/gateway/trunk

./configure --with-mysql --with-malloc=native

## –> you will get a message saying thank you for using Kannel.

touch .depend
make depend
make

sudo make bindir=/kannel/bin/ install  #—-> Enter your root password.

## and congratz

Answer (score 2):

Howto start & stop the bearerbox & smsbox

```
#/usr/sbin/smsbox /etc/kannel.conf &
#/usr/sbin/bearerbox /etc/kannel.conf &
```

Howto Stop the kannel service

```
#/etc/init.d/kannel stop
```

Howto check logs for kannel

```
 #tail -20f /sdp/wap_push_promotion/bearerbox.log
```

Howto check the kannel process is running or not?

```
#  ps -ef | grep kannel
root     11314 11281  0 14:05 pts/2    00:00:00 grep kannel
kannel   20609    1  0 Aug02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/bearerbox /etc/kannel.conf
kannel   20628    1  0 Aug02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smsbox/etc/kannel.conf
```

Read more about how to configure and use kannel here
http://www.techgyaan.org/2011/09/how-to-install-kannel-open-souce-sms/

Answer (score 0):

here are some tips:

http://julmis.julmajanne.com/index.php/Kannel

Comment: Great link. Edit your post with the most useful information from the link so that you answer won't cease to be useful when the link is down.

Answer (score 0):

First decide where to install it:

```
./conifgure --prefix=/usr/local/kannel
```

Then run make to create binaries

```
make
```

Then make install to put the correct binaries in their right places

```
make install
```

Finally go to /usr/local/kannel and start the bearerbox and smsbox

```
./sbin/bearerbox smskannel.conf &
./sbin/smsbox smskannel.conf &
```

`smskannel.conf` is and example configuration distributed with the source code and you can copy it to your installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

- Download version 1.5.0:“https://redmine.kannel.org/attachments/download/198/gateway-1.5.0.tar.gz”
- Uncompress

  $ curl -O https://redmine.kannel.org/attachments/download/198/gateway-1.5.0.tar.gz

  $ tar -zxvf gateway-1.5.0.tar.gz

  $ cd gateway-1.5.0
- Select a target install directory (different from your current directory) for the —prefix flag (for ex. /home/vtypal/kannel)
- Build and install as usual

  $ ./configure --prefix=/home/vtypal/kannel

  $ make

  $ make install
- Under the sbin directory of kannel create a configuration file called kannel.conf with your kannel configuration.
- Start kannel 
  $ cd /home/vtypal/kannel/sbin

  $ nohup ./bearerbox &

  $ nohup ./smsbox &
- Check the logs if you have any config error in your kannel.conf